# wchar_t argv in C -- Unicode

Tags: c, unicode, command-line

Does GCC support the Microsoft equivalent of wmain()?  I'm writing C program and need to use Unicode throughout.  If not, can char be converted to wchar_t?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need `wchar_t` for Unicode.  You can use `char` for the `utf-8` encoding of Unicode.  Plus, `wchar_t` can be different sizes.  On Windows, it is 16 bits, but on many Linux/Unix platforms it is 32 bits.

For more info specific to GCC, see this post I found via a Google search:

http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnu.mingw.user/22962

(According to that, the answer to your question of whether GCC supports `wmain` is "no".)

Comment: Both your answer and Vijay's answer below are very good.  However this response is the answer to the question I asked.

Answer (score 2):

Many of C's standard string functions are encoding agnostic. You can use `char*` to store UTF-8 encoded strings and use them safely with:

```
strcpy strncpy strcat strncat strcmp strncmp strdup strchr 
strrchr strcspn strspn strpbrk strstr strtok
```

Some other functions will not give you correct results with Unicode strings. For example, `strlen` always count bytes, not characters. The number of characters can be counted in C in a portable way using `mbstowcs(NULL,s,0)`. It will return the number of characters in `s` successfully translated to `wchar_t`. This works for UTF-8 like for any other supported encoding, as long as the appropriate locale has been selected.

If you want to do advanced operations on Unicode strings like complex code page conversions, regular expressions, text wrapping on word boundaries etc, I suggest you use a good library like [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/).

Refer: [Using Unicode in C/C++](http://evanjones.ca/unicode-in-c.html).

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  It is very informative.  I intend to use ICU for conversion.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process Unicode command line arguments without `wmain`, you can use the argument-less standard `main` functions and the Windows API functions [`GetCommandLineW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683156.aspx), [`CommandLineToArgvW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776391.aspx), and [`LocalFree`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366730.aspx). `CommandLineToArgvW` uses the same [same rules for command line parsing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17w5ykft.aspx) as the Microsoft runtime library.

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to use wide strings, `mbstowcs` will convert a multi-byte string to a `wchar_t` string. The encoding it assumes the multi-byte string is in depends on the LC_CTYPE category of the current locale. It's necessary to set this with `setlocale`; otherwise you will get the "C" locale by default.

The question remains of what character encoding is used in `argv`. This could be UTF-8, or it could be one of the single-byte encodings like Latin-1. This depends on your terminal settings. Experimenting with xterm, I got different values for `argv` when I passed "é" on the command line, depending on the value of LANG that xterm inherited: for LANG=en_US.UTF-8, it gave "c3 a9"; for LANG=en_US, it gave "e9" (I think this is Latin-1.)

You can get the locale from the environment with `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "")` or `setlocale(LC_ALL, "")` first to use the correct multi-byte format (set from environmental variables). You will have problems if LANG is changed after the terminal emulator is started, though.

glibc provides several other functions for character set conversion which may be more appropriate - see the "Character Set Handling" section of the glibc manual for more information. My experience is that converting a string in argv to a given encoding is quite tricky and it may have to be done in two stages: once to convert it to `wchar_t` format, and secondly to convert it from `wchar_t` to the desired encoding (e.g. UTF-8).

Comment: I think that it's really strange since Latin-1 and UTF-8 are backward-compatible.

Comment: No, Latin-1 and UTF-8 are not backward-compatible. The encoding of the character `é` in Latin-1 is `E9` while the encoding in UTF-8 is `C3 A9`. They are completely different. Not at all compatible. Cheers.